# postman only showing "This field is required" to ManyToMany field in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models - Module and Room. A module can have zero or multiple rooms and a room can be added into multiple modules. So, there is a simple many-to-many relationship between them.

When I use post request, raw-data works, but not form-data.

module/models.py -

```
class Module(models.Model):
    module_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    room_list = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Rooms, blank=True)
```

rooms/models.py -

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

module/serializers.py -

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rooms_data = validated_data.pop('rooms')
        module = Module.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in rooms_data:
            room = Rooms.objects.get(**data)
            module.rooms.add(room)
        return module

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # Updating rooms
        rooms_data = validated_data.get('rooms')
        instance.rooms.clear()
        
        for room_data in rooms_data:
            room = Rooms.objects.get(**room_data)
            instance.rooms.add(room)
        
        # Updating other fields
        fields = [
            'title',
            'desc',
            'thumbnail',
            'is_deleted',
        ]
        for field in fields:
            setattr(instance, field, validated_data[field])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

rooms/serialier.py -

```
class RoomSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    room_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Rooms
        fields = "__all__"
```

module/views.py -

```py
class add_module(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
    
        # Adding the rooms to module from room_list
        new_request = request.data.copy()
        room_list=[]
        if 'room_list' in new_request:
            room_list_data = list(new_request['room_list'].split(" "))
            for room in room_list_data:
                room_object = Rooms.objects.get(room_id=room)
                room_serializer = RoomSerializer(room_object)
                room_list.append(room_serializer.data)
        new_request.update({'rooms':room_list})
    
        # creating the module
        module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(data=new_request)
        if module_serializer.is_valid():
            module_serializer.save()
            return Response(module_serializer.data['module_id'])
        return Response(module_serializer.errors)
```

POST request body for updating a module in POSTMAN -

```
{
    "module_id": 2,
    "room_list": "1 2",
    "title": "4",
    "desc": "22",
}
```

Pls notice that while taking input of ManyToMany field - "rooms", I'm taking a string "room_list" as input that contains all the room_ids to be included. This works perfectly fine when I take input as raw-data in postman, but when I use form-data, it shows

```
{
    "rooms": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, serializer fields with (many=True) create nested objects.
If you input data with `Rooms` as already serialized, then it means that you create other `Rooms` instances. It will be shown with `if module_serializer.is_valid():` part. Therefore, if you intended to implement as just link already instantiated `Rooms` to `Module`, it's better to make it as primary key list.

Here are my example codes.

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rooms_data = validated_data['room_list']
        module = Module.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in rooms_data.split(' '):
            room = Rooms.objects.get(room_id=data)
            module.rooms.add(room)
        return module

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):

        # Updating rooms
        rooms_data = validated_data.get('rooms')
        instance.rooms.clear()

        for room_data in rooms_data:
            room = Rooms.objects.get(**room_data)
            instance.rooms.add(room)

        # Updating other fields
        fields = [
            'title',
            'desc',
            'thumbnail',
            'is_deleted',
        ]
        for field in fields:
            setattr(instance, field, validated_data[field])
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = '__all__'
```

```
class AddModule(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # creating the module
        module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if module_serializer.is_valid():
            module_serializer.save()
            return Response(module_serializer.data['module_id'])
        return Response(module_serializer.errors)
```

Any other parts are same as yours. Regardless of whether data are sent by form-data or json raw data, results are same as below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for yr amazing effort man. It worked!

Comment: One more thing, there is no list field in django. Is there any way to input room_list as a list instead of string?

Comment: If you remove read_only=True option in RoomSerializer field in Module Serializer, you can receive rooms as a list. But, drf serializer would try to create new Rooms instance with that data. 

If you want to make relations between Rooms and Module through serializers, PrimaryKeyField can be an option. You can receive data with primary key list of Rooms. But, if you want to use this field with serialization, to_representation method should be overriden.